# How do I view logs for a failed cron job in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

One of the daily cron jobs I defined in cron.yaml failed on my live webapp2 app.

Is there a way to view say standard error output, stack traces, or logs in general from App Engine cron jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the consolidated logs, you should be able to look at the time your job was supposed to run.  Crashes should be in the logs, but you need to hook up logging for it to show up there.

Answer (score 1):

These do show up in the logs.  Perhaps do a regex search for 'AppEngine-Google', as that will show up in the user-agent header for cron jobs and taskqueues.